# Error sending WebRequest to Spreedly with C# : (422) Unprocessable Entity

Tags: c#, api, curl, webrequest, spreedly

I'm working with Spreedly, and I'm running into what I would assume is a minor problem.

For the life of me I don't understand why my code isn't sending my context correctly...

This is my code (credentials have been changed) that returns the error (422) Unprocessable Entity, which I can only assume means something is wrong with the XML that is being sent, but it appears to be correct when I set a break point.

```
string url = "https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways.xml";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "Content-type: application/xml";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Ll6fAtoVSTyVMlJEmtpoJV8Shw5", "RKOCG5D8D3fZxDSg504D0IxU2XD4Io5VXmyzdCtTivHFTTSylzM2ZzTWFwVH4ucG");
XElement xelement = new XElement("gateway", new XElement("gateway_type", "test"));
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xelement.ToString());
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqstr.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I don't use WebRequest often, so it's more than plausible that I'm missing something simple.

Spreedly keeps their documentation [here](https://docs.spreedly.com/).

The examples are in curl and say I should be sending the following:

```
$ curl https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways.xml \
-u 'Ll6fAtoVSTyVMlJEmtpoJV8Shw5:RKOCG5D8D3fZxDSg504D0IxU2XD4Io5VXmyzdCtTivHFTTSylzM2ZzTWFwVH4ucG' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
-d '<gateway>
      <gateway_type>test</gateway_type>
    </gateway>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider one of two Github repos instead of reinventing the wheel in C#: https://github.com/malixsys/Spreedly.Net and https://github.com/philjones88/SpreedlyCoreSharp both implement most of the functionality you'd be looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

Spreedly return 422 in case of failure in the transaction.
Try use HttpClient instead WebRequest.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", 
"ENVIRONMENT_KEY:ACCESS_SECRET");
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

string responseJson;
using (HttpContent resp = response.Content)
{
    responseJson = resp.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
}

return responseJson;
```